# A function satisfying $f''(x)(1+f(x))=1+x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

> let $f$ be defined for $x\ge 0$ and has a continous derivative and $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$ such that $$f''(x)(1+f(x))=1+x$$Then the range that $f(1)$ can take-

I think the key to the question is to find a function whose derivetive/double derivative is $f''(x)(1+f(x))$.So far i have thought of using,$H(x)=e^xf(x)$ but $H''(x)$ is coming to be quite messy.

Also integrating both sides;$$f'(x)=\int \frac{1+x}{1+f(x)} $$.

I think it has something to do with finding some bound on $f'(x)$ and then using LMVT?

Comment: What is the LMVT?

Comment: @АлександрПальма Langranges mean value theorem

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705582/differential-equation-monotonicity1fxfx-1x?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there exists some $x_0 \ge 0$ such that $f(x_0)+1=0$. Then, from the given equality, we get $1 + x_0 = 0$. Hence, there does not exist such $x_0$.

Since $f$ is continuous and the function $f(x)+1$ is non-zero, for all $x$ in $[0, \infty)$ we have $1+f(x) > 0$. Therefore, $\forall x: ~f''(x) >0$. It means that $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing. Since $f'(0) = 1$, we get that $\forall x: ~f'(x) > 0$, as well. Hence, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing too.

Now, since $f(0)=1$, we must have (at least) $f(1) > 1$.